# Is there a security threat when search query is given as an array and it returns a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

In a Rails application, when the search query parameter `q` is given as `/search?q[0]=hi&q[1]=hello` in the URL, it returned an output such as 
`No result for "{"0"=>"hi, "1"=>"hello"}"`.

Are there any risks with this behaviour, like for example Ruby code injections?

Comment: We'd need to see the code handling this. But theoretically, yes, there is a possibility of an exploit anytime you're outputting user input.

Comment: @drs, the application is escaping double quotes and other html characters as well from user input. The thing is whether any evaluation such as mathematic operations can be carried out? The application is expected to receive and display the user content as string. As you can see the hash output I mentioned earlier., it displays every thing in double quotes. But I too have doubts on this behaviour. Can you please explain how this behaviour occurs. ? Whether its there in every rail application?